# UITextField not resizing fonts size while editing

Tags: uitextfield

I am using text field with all properties set,
It is not resizing the fonts while editing and text goes out of the view in textfield

```
txtTitle.font = [UIFont fontWithName:@"Helvetica" size:15.0f];
[txtTitle setMinimumFontSize:3.0];
[txtTitle setAdjustsFontSizeToFitWidth:YES];
```

It resizes to some extent then it same result as text going beyond the view text field

Answer (score 5, accepted):

I know its a old thread , but still incase you did not figure out .
this is a bug and following can be used as a workaround.
Make a category on UITextField and write following methods and call it when font size need to be change to fit width of textfield.

```
- (void)adjustFontSizeToFit
{
UIFont *font = self.font;
CGSize size = self.frame.size;
for (CGFloat maxSize = self.font.pointSize; maxSize >= self.minimumFontSize; maxSize -= 1.f)
{
    font = [font fontWithSize:maxSize];
    CGSize constraintSize = CGSizeMake(size.width, MAXFLOAT);
    CGSize labelSize = [self.text sizeWithFont:font constrainedToSize:constraintSize lineBreakMode:UILineBreakModeWordWrap];
// Keeping the width constant if given text requires more height , decrease the font size.
    if(labelSize.height <= size.height)
    {
        self.font = font;
        [self setNeedsLayout];
        break;
    }
}
// set the font to the minimum size anyway
self.font = font;
[self setNeedsLayout];
}
```

Comment: update code to use boundingRectWithSize instead of sizeWithFont.  Also, take into account of placeholder.  [Gist here](https://gist.github.com/hermanccw/3fbf5df207854d0191b4)

Answer (score 4):

Thank you, Ankit! It works for me. I had to update a deprecated methods: sizeWithFont

```
- (void)adjustFontSizeToFit {

    UIFont *font = self.font;
    CGSize size = self.frame.size;

    for (CGFloat maxSize = self.font.pointSize; maxSize >= self.minimumFontSize; maxSize -= 1.f) {

        font = [font fontWithSize:maxSize];
        //CGSize constraintSize = CGSizeMake(size.width, MAXFLOAT);
        //CGSize labelSize = [self.text sizeWithFont:font constrainedToSize:constraintSize lineBreakMode:UILineBreakModeWordWrap];

        NSAttributedString *attributedText =  [[NSAttributedString alloc] initWithString:self.text
     attributes:@ { NSFontAttributeName: font  }];

        CGRect rect = [attributedText boundingRectWithSize:(CGSize){size.width, CGFLOAT_MAX} options:NSStringDrawingUsesLineFragmentOrigin context:nil];

        CGSize labelSize = rect.size;

        // Keeping the width constant if given text requires more height , decrease the font size.
        if(labelSize.height <= size.height) {
            self.font = font;
            [self setNeedsLayout];
            break;
        }
     }
     // set the font to the minimum size anyway
     self.font = font;
     [self setNeedsLayout];
}
```

Answer (score 0):

Swift Answer:

```
extension UITextField {

func adjustFontSizeToFitHeight(minFontSize : CGFloat, maxFontSize : CGFloat) {
    guard let labelText: NSString = text else {
        return
    }

    guard let font: UIFont = self.font else {
        return
    }

    let labelHeight = frame.size.height

    guard labelHeight != 0 else {
        return
    }

    // replace with newton's method
    for size in minFontSize.stride(to: maxFontSize, by: 0.1) {

        let textHeight = labelText.sizeWithAttributes([NSFontAttributeName: font.fontWithSize(size)]).height

        if textHeight > labelHeight {
            self.font = font.fontWithSize(max(size - 0.1, minFontSize))
            return
        }
    }
    self.font = font.fontWithSize(maxFontSize)
}

}
```

Comment: Although this code may be help to solve the problem,
providing additional context regarding _why_ and/or _how_ it
answers the question would significantly improve its
long-term value.  Please [edit] your answer to add some
explanation.